# tmux refresh display after terminal width change

Tags: terminal, tmux

With `screen`, in a terminal that's 80 columns wide, I can do something like:

```
for i in $(seq 81); do echo -n "m"; done; echo
```

and then resize the window to be a little wider, and the last 'm' jumps up to where it would have been had I run the command before resizing the window. I'm really loving `tmux` but am missing this lovely feature from `screen`... Is there any way to make `tmux` do this (some hidden `recompute-width` command I haven't found yet)?

---

EDIT: 2013-07-24

As of February 2013, reflow is supported by tmux!

[Here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/8903c1f167839569b7514508b38988aa6486575c)'s the commit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of February 2013, reflow is supported by tmux!

[Here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/8903c1f167839569b7514508b38988aa6486575c)'s the commit.

Comment: How ironic. I came here to figure out how to disable this feature after updating my version.

Comment: @philo should be fixed shortly

Answer (score 7):

*tmux* does not currently support “reflow” or “rewrap” (following the behavior of *xterm*).

The author of *tmux* has written several times that he does not personally like the reflow behavior of *screen*, but that he would consider incorporating it into *tmux* (as an option, presumably) if someone else were to implement it.

Mailing list references (older first; not an exhaustive list, just what I pulled up with a bit of searching):

- [Text Redraw/Reflow tmux vs screen](http://news.gmane.org/find-root.php?message_id=%3c20100728231111.GC12739%40yelena.nicm.ath.cx%3e)
- [2 questions about working with tmux](http://news.gmane.org/find-root.php?message_id=%3c20110118163301.GB32518%40yelena.nicm.ath.cx%3e)
- [Redo line wrapping on resize](http://news.gmane.org/find-root.php?message_id=%3c20110604093016.GF1455%40yelena.nicm.ath.cx%3e)

Comment: Awesome thanks for the info. I just might have a whack at it...

Comment: All the links are dead now.